# How does a vacuum pump's head correlate with its absolute vacuum pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

I suspect that a vacuum pump's head is related to its absolute vacuum pressure but I can't find a straight answer as to how, so here is an example that demonstrates what I am asking. Say I have a 3 CFM two-stage vacuum pump that has an absolute vacuum pressure of 22.5 microns (which is .0225 torr if I am not mistaken, yes?). What, then, is the absolute vacuum pressure at each stage? If I were to connect two of these pumps in series to increase the pump's head, what would the absolute vacuum pressure be?

Comment: 1. the pressure in each stage will depend on the actual pump design. Different sources will have different designs. 2. Randomly stacking pumps may not give you what you think at all.